# SQL get a result from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
 table : game

 id     mdate             stadium                 team1     team2
1001    8 June 2012     National Stadium, Warsaw    POL     GRE
1002    8 June 2012     Stadion Miejski (Wroclaw)   RUS     CZE
1003    12 June 2012    Stadion Miejski (Wroclaw)   GRE     CZE
1004    12 June 2012    National Stadium, Warsaw    POL     RUS
....

 table goal 

 matchid    teamid  player              gtime
 1001        POL    Robert Lewandowski      17
 1001        GRE    Dimitris Salpingidis    51
 1002        RUS    Alan Dzagoev            15
 1002        RUS    Roman Pavlyuchenko      82
 ...
```

Attention: the above two tables are long so the result table may show some rows that are not displayed in the two tables.

Need to find every match with the goals scored by each team

```
 mdate         team1    score1  team2   score2
 1 July 2012    ESP        4    ITA     0
 10 June 2012   ESP        1    ITA     1
 10 June 2012   IRL        1    CRO     3
```

My solution :

```
  SELECT a.mdate, team1, score1, team2, score2
  FROM
  (
       SELECT mdate, team1,
               SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team1 THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0
                   END) AS score1
        FROM game 
        INNER JOIN goal
        ON id = matchid
        GROUP BY mdate, team1  
   ) AS a
  INNER JOIN 
  (
        SELECT mdate, team2,
                SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team2 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS score2
        FROM game 
      INNER JOIN goal
      ON id = matchid
      GROUP BY mdate, team2
  ) AS b
  ON       
  a.mdate = b.mdate
  ORDER   BY a.mdate, team1, team2
```

I am not sure my solution is correct but its structure is long and ugly.

Anyone can suggest a better solution ?

is it possible to solve it with CASE WHEN ?

Comment: one observation would be that perhaps you might have multiple games on the same day and thus mdate would not be unique to serve as the join key. 

Also, please consider normalizing your player names.

Your query is fine, in terms of aesthetics, that's just kind of the way it works. @daniel_machet below has a nice way of cleaning your sub-selects up, but PLEASE don't use implicit joins.

Comment: @zentechinc, thanks, is it possible to solve it with CASE WHEN ?

Comment: Of course. Seems like your case when's are working fine. However, its probably not best practice in terms of SQL and set theory. You would be better of using the sub-selects given their efficiency. The case when's tend to be iterative in nature.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method might be correlated subqueries:

```
select m.mdate, m.team1,
   (select count(*)
    from goal g
    where g.teamid = m.team1 and g.matchid = m.id
   ) as team1_goals,
   m.team2,
   (select count(*)
    from goal g
    where g.teamid = m.team2 and g.matchid = m.id
   ) as team2_goals
from game m
ORDER BY m.mdate, m.team1, m.team2;
```

One advantage of this approach is that it can take advantage of an index on `goals(matchid, teamid)`.

Comment: Nice one - seems much simpler... for my benefit... why is this returning 0 when there are no records returned by team1_goals / team2_goals where LEFT OUTER was returning NULL (and thus needed CASE to rectify per the problem set)?

Comment: @DanielMachet . . . An aggregation query without a `GROUP BY` always returns one row.  If there are no matches, then `COUNT(*)` returns `0` and not `NULL` (although other aggregations will return `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

OK... found the site and got this to work

```
SELECT g.mdate, g.team1, CASE WHEN g2.score1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g2.score1 END, g.team2, CASE WHEN g3.score2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g3.score2 END 
FROM game g LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT matchid, teamid, COUNT(*) score1 from goal group by matchid, teamid) g2 ON g.team1 = g2.teamid AND g.id = g2.matchid
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (SELECT matchid, teamid, COUNT(*) score2 from goal group by matchid, teamid) g3 ON g.team2 = g3.teamid AND g.id = g3.matchid 
ORDER BY g.mdate, g.team1, g.team2
```

wow... mariadb is pretty vicious on case of table names etc.

The CASE is there to deal with the scenario where null is returned

Comment: That depends... is it for your own curiosity or is that what the question paper says?

Comment: I try to avoid implicit, and also, I got some hints about CASE WHEN may be solution.

Comment: I tested your query but the result is not correct. Some rows are missing.

Comment: yeah the implicit joins weren't left outer joins (you need left outer to cater for games where one of the teams don't score which is likely a frequent occurrence) have tweaked to make them so and added explicit joins at bottom

Comment: I have run your new query at http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation, Question13. But, the results do not match the answers. thanks